AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
current_users = ['machina', 'bezbazarov', 'kocherginr', 'komap', 'qwerty', 'BezbazarovAA']

new_users = ['Bezbazarov', 'arnold', 'kingkong', 'komap', 'byxapecT']

for new_user in new_users:

    if new_user.lower() in current_users.lower():
        print (f'Извини, имя {new_user.title()}, занято. Выбери другое!')
    else:
        print (f'Имя {new_user}, свободно. Добро пожаловать!')

Необходимо, чтобы имена проверялись в обох списках по нижнему регистру.
Если убираю .lower в current_users, то все работает, но проверка идет не верно...так как lower задействуется только для списка new_users

Метод .lower() доступен только для строк, а вы пытаетесь применить его к списку.
Как вариант, можно собрать множество с элементами в нижнем регистре и уже сравнивать с ним.
current_users = ['machina', 'bezbazarov', 'kocherginr', 'komap', 'qwerty', 'BezbazarovAA']

new_users = ['Bezbazarov', 'arnold', 'kingkong', 'komap', 'byxapecT']

# Собираем множество с именами в нижнем регистре
current_users_lower_set = {user.lower() for user in current_users}

for new_user in new_users:

    if new_user.lower() in current_users_lower_set:
        print (f'Извини, имя {new_user.title()}, занято. Выбери другое!')
    else:
        print (f'Имя {new_user}, свободно. Добро пожаловать!')

Вывод:
Извини, имя Bezbazarov, занято. Выбери другое!
Имя arnold, свободно. Добро пожаловать!
Имя kingkong, свободно. Добро пожаловать!
Извини, имя Komap, занято. Выбери другое!
Имя byxapecT, свободно. Добро пожаловать!


Спасибо за помощь!

Для проверок in лучше уж тогда множество собрать, раз всё-равно делаете новую коллекцию.

@CrazyElf в рамках этой задачи думаю разницы не будет, но с замечанием согласен и учёл в ответе.

@Amgarak С таким количеством элементов коллекции да, разницы не будет, но лучше сразу показывать хорошие практики и объяснять их, чтобы у людей перед глазами были правильные примеры )
